# Convergence of series with nonnegative terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume that there exists an increasing function L from [2,∞) into (0,∞) which satisfies L(x^n)=nL(x). Determine whether the series $\sum^{∞}_{n=2}1/nL(n)$ converge or diverge.

Here is my reasoning:since 1/L(n) is a decreasing sequence with nonnegative terms. I want to prove that $\sum^{∞}_{n=2}1/L(2^n)$ converges. Then, by $2^n$ test, $\sum^{∞}_{n=2}1/nL(n)$ converges.

The partial sum of $\sum^{∞}_{n=2}1/L(2^n)$, denote as sn, is bounded by n/L(4) since 1/L is a decreasing function. Therefore, we can conclude that $\sum^{∞}_{n=2}1/L(2^n)$ converges. However, when I apply ratio test, $\lim_{n\to∞}|L(2^{n+1})/L(2^{n})|=1$, which means inconclusive. There must be something wrong in my proof. Could anyone help me with my proof? Thank you.

Comment: You beat me by *one* second, but mine is an answer, so I will probably get more points.

Comment: I don't see why there has to be something wrong with your proof just because the ratio test is inconclusive. Can you explain? Also, that the partial sums are bounded by $n/L(4)$ does not help you much, since $n/L(4)\to \infty$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$L(n)
=\ln(n)
$.
Then $L(n)$ satisfies
$L(x^n)
=n \cdot L(x)
$.

But
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac1{n \ln(n)}
$
diverges.

Therefore,
in this case,
the sum diverges.

Comment: Though L(n) has the same property as ln(n), I do not think you can assume that L(n)=ln(n).

Comment: @Leila: No,you cannot. But at least, it shows that your proof is wrong,since we **could** have $L(n)=\ln (n)$.

Comment: I can show that if L is differentiable then it is a multiple of log. I think I can do this if L is continuous. I may propose this as a question.